# casperjs does not recognize global variable stored between then statements

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

so I call the first url ... it returns a JSON object , I store the JSON object in a global variable called `global_input` .... and then I open a link using  `global_input.token`

```
  var global_input = {'token' : 'xxx'} ;


    casper.start('http://localhost/client/charg/que' , function (content) {


     })
    .then(function() {
       global_input  = JSON.parse(this.getPageContent());
       casper.log( ' ==== token === > ' + global_input.token    , 'debug');

    })
    .thenOpen('http://localhost/client/charg/go/' + global_input.token , function() {

    })

    .run(function(){
        this.echo("DONE1");
        this.exit();
    });
```

here is the log

```
page init .....
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/5 http://localhost/client/charg/que (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/5: done in 725ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/5 http://localhost/client/charg/que (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom]  ==== token === > e608e91335fd622f430692d40e7ddf0f4b63428d
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/5: done in 750ms.
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://localhost/client/charg/go/xxx, HTTP GET
```

as you can see, even though the log shows the `token` being set to a new value

```
==== token === > e608e91335fd622f430692d40e7ddf0f4b63428d
```

in the next step i still get the default value of token which was `xxx`

```
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://localhost/client/charg/go/xxx, HTTP GET
```

am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your global_input is registered with it's initial value in the thenOpen method.

like this

```
  casper.start(static url , callback method)
        .then(callback method)
        .thenOpen(static url (here, initial global object is used) , callback method)
        .run(callback method);
```

So if you change anything in static_url, casperjs will not know as it already registered those urls in the casperjs' execution stack.

You need to do like this

```
var global_input = {'token' : 'xxx'} ;

// this method will be called again when evaluating the url
function getGlobalToken() {
    return global_input.token;
}
```

Now call get method like this

```
thenOpen('http://localhost/client/charg/go/' + getGlobalToken() , function() {

    })
```